# Suspicious error using polyglossia with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

I know that biblatex doesn't currently support polyglossia. I am the one trying to add support for this to biblatex ...

I am looking for an opinion on this following strangeness which I am trying to understand as part of this endeavour. Take this MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{test,
  hyphenation = {german},
  author = {Zakery Zokon},
  title = {In Honore Salvatoris~"=Vom Sinn und Unsinn der Patrozinienkunde},
  journaltitle = {Revue d'Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique},
  volume = {97},
  year = {2002},
  pages = {431--456, 791--823},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[babelshorthands]{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english} 
\setotherlanguages{german} 
\usepackage[language=auto,babel=other,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\begin{document} 
\noindent 
\cite{test} 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

In the log, I see:

```
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 31 was incomplete)
```

This is suspicious but I can't see what line 31 it's referring to and would appreciate any pointers. I am trying to find out if there is some bug in polyglossia which is causing problems.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with biblatex; the error occurs when you just load polyglossia with babel shorthands and German.

Comment: The line number refers imho to gloss-german.ldf and to a bug in polyglossia which has been already reported.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you point to this bug report. I can't see any problems around line 31 of gloss-german.ldf. The `\ifx` starting on line 31 of babelsh.def has a missing `\fi`. When I add that the error resolves.

Comment: It's a missing `\fi` in the `babelsh.def` file. Line 31 starts with `\ifx\PackageError\@undefined` and this `\ifx` has no matching `\fi`; just add it after line 65. See https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/50

Comment: @Audrey: sorry I meant the babelsh.def bug (I run into it with a german document). Being exact on a smartphone is difficult;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Not a problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug that's already fixed in the main repository.

Comment: To properly close the question, I add that the fixed version of `babelsh.def` has been placed in the TeX Live repository; this is the link for the "diff": http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/babelsh.def?sortby=date&r1=31010&r2=31009&pathrev=31010

Comment: Thanks to all, I agree that this is off-topic - I was looking for the new polyglossia fork on github to check for tickets but searching for polyglossia there only returns the old one so thanks for the link to the new one.